# can't populate table because of vague syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to populate one table from my database on phpmyadmin, so I have this script:

```
USE avi; //database


SET @listOfStates = 'AK, AL, AR, AS, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DC, DE, FL, GA, GU, HI, IA, ID, IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD, ME, MI, MN, MO, MP, MS, MT, NC, ND, NE, NH, NJ, NM, NV, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, PR, RI, SC, SD, TN, TX, UM, UT, VA, VI, VT, WA, WI, WV, WY';

SET @item = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@listOfStates, ',', 1); 
SET @itemValue = 0;

CREATE PROCEDURE populate()
BEGIN
SET @strLen = LENGTH(@listOfStates); 

label1: LOOP

    SET @strLen = LENGTH(@listOfStates);
    SET @item = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@listOfStates, ',', 1); 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @itemValue FROM us_accidents u WHERE u.state LIKE item;

    INSERT INTO state_cases (name, cases) VALUES (@item, @itemValue);

    SET @SubStrLen = LENGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(listOfStates, ',', 1));
    SET @listOfStates =  MID(listOfStates, SubStrLen, strLen);

    IF listOfStates = NULL
        LEAVE label1;
    ITERATE label1;

    END LOOP label1;


END;
```

when I'm trying to import I get this

[image]

Am I using SET @ wrong? or is something wrong with my procedures or even the varchar?

I mention that the table is already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are missing the `DELIMITER` command before the start of the stored procedure.

Also, the `IF` statement at the end of the procedure is malformed: the syntax is `IF ... THEN ... END IF;`. And, finally, to check for nullness you need `IS NULL` rather than `= NULL`.

This compiles successfully:

```
SET @listOfStates = 'AK, AL, AR, AS, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DC, DE, FL, GA, GU, HI, IA, ID, IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD, ME, MI, MN, MO, MP, MS, MT, NC, ND, NE, NH, NJ, NM, NV, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, PR, RI, SC, SD, TN, TX, UM, UT, VA, VI, VT, WA, WI, WV, WY';

SET @item = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@listOfStates, ',', 1); 
SET @itemValue = 0;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE populate()
BEGIN
    SET @strLen = LENGTH(@listOfStates); 

    label1: LOOP

        SET @strLen = LENGTH(@listOfStates);
        SET @item = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@listOfStates, ',', 1); 
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @itemValue FROM us_accidents u WHERE u.state LIKE item;

        INSERT INTO state_cases (name, cases) VALUES (@item, @itemValue);

        SET @SubStrLen = LENGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(listOfStates, ',', 1));
        SET @listOfStates =  MID(listOfStates, SubStrLen, strLen);

        IF listOfStates IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE label1;
        END IF;

        ITERATE label1;

    END LOOP label1;

END; 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is LENGHT a synonym for LENGTH or some other MySQL specific?

Comment: @TomC: I would take this as a typo.

Comment: Thats what I was hoping but it *looks* like a cut and paste.